# Cufon Not Working in IE - A CSS Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cufon

I'm having the oddest problem. I'm building a theme for Wordpress using Cufon. Cufon works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but I couldn't get it to render in IE, so, since I'm still in the middle of development, I set the problem aside to deal with later.

Sometime yesterday, I was fiddling with other CSS elements in my theme. Later, I opened the theme in IE8 to test alignment, and wallah, the Cufon had started working. I wasn't sure why, as I'd changed quite a bit of CSS, but hey - as long as it works.

Then, stupidly, I overwrote my old CSS code, reverting back to before my edits, and the Cufon broke again. Since I don't know what I did to fix it in the first place, I'm in a bind, but now I know it can be done.

I've googled and googled, and I can't seem to find any reason why this should be the case. The CSS validates. The HTML validates. The Firefox Error consol shows no errors on page load. And it seems to be a CSS issue, as this was the only file changed.

If it makes any difference, I'm building on Wordpress 3.0.

I'm embedding Cufon in the header of each page with this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/Yanone_Kaffeesatz_Rg_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h2.posttitle');
    Cufon.replace('#topnav > ul > li');
    Cufon.replace('.rightwidget > h2');
    Cufon.replace('.footerrightli > h2');
    Cufon.replace('.footerleftli > h2');
    Cufon.replace('.footermiddleli > h2');
    </script>
```

The development site is here: [link removed]

I sure would appreciate some help. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think there's a lesson here: use a version control system like git/bzr/etc (and actually use it more than once a day) so you have decent revisions of all your files.

Comment: Hah, yes, that's definitely one lesson. The other lesson being "take the time to figure out how you solved your issues before moving on". Which is the lesson I'm working on now.

Comment: It would be helpful to see both the final HTML output (a view-source would work), and the complete CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the Sizzle Selector utility for IE, it works hand-in-hand with Cufon, as all of your replacements are non-basic strings (like `H2`, `li`).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the cufon script works with IE9.  Make sure you have v1.09i or higher installed in your theme or plugin directory in WordPress.

For example, to fix our custom theme on our site so H1/H2/H3 tags used the cufon fonts (they were showing blank in IE9), we pulled the latest download to our server and put in our theme's ./js/ directory as "cufon-yui.js".  Problem solved.

Download from:
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Supporting documentation about this issue:
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#wiki-faq-1